# Understanding conditional probabilities in Bayes classifiers in the wikipedia page example

Tags: probability

I'm using the [wikipedia page example](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Naive_Bayes_classifier&oldid=453953061):

Why is $P(\text{height} \mid \text{male}) = 1.5789$? This means the probability of height given male? The [talk page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3aNaive_Bayes_classifier#Sex_classification_example) has a similar question, unanswered.

> the example added last august about sex classification is puzzling me,
>   could anyone tell me how to compute the $P(\text{height} \mid \text{man})$?
>   The author gave the value 1.5789 with a note stating that "probability
>   distribution over one is OK. It is the area under the bell curve that
>   is equal to one" which also puzzle me.

Answer (score 2):

The value $1.5789$ that is calculated is the *density* of the probability mass
at $x = 6$ with units mass/foot; it is *not* the probability that a randomly selected male has height *exactly* $6$ feet.  To get a probability, you have to multiply the value of the probability density by a length.  In other words, 
the probability that a randomly selected male has height *between* $5$ feet, $11\frac{1}{2}$ inches and $6$ feet, $\frac{1}{2}$ inches is *approximately*
$1.5789 \times \frac{1}{12}$ (because the unit of height ($x$ axis) is a foot and
thus the length in question is  $1$ inch = $\frac{1}{12}$ foot).  Note that
the value of the probability that we thus obtain is an *approximation*, but a very good approximation in this instance.  (To get an exact value, we would 
need to compute the value of an integral, but $1.5789/12 = 0.1315\ldots$ is 
good enough for gummint purposes).

As a practical matter, heights are often recorded to the nearest inch, and so
when someone says a particular male is $6$ feet tall, people usually take it to
mean that the person is between $5$'$11\frac{1}{2}$" and $6$'$\frac{1}{2}$"
anyway.  But in this sense of the phrase, the probability that a randomly chosen
male is $6$ feet tall is $13.15\%$, not $157.89\%$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in this case we should use **Normal distribution** for the trainig set, therefore start to calculate all you need for distribution

1. $\mu = \frac{6 + 5.92 + 5.58 + 5.92}{4} = 5.855 $ - mean value
2. next find the variance $\sigma ^ 2$

and substitute to the formula of Normal distribution with f(x=6) as a testing value

Answer (score 0):

The male height distribution is approximated from the training set to be a normal distribution with mean $\mu = 5.855$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 0.035$. The likelihood of seeing a height of 6 feet given that the sample is male is therefore

$$P(6 | \textrm{male}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2}} \exp\left( \frac{ (6 - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \approx 1.579$$

which is the quoted likelihood in the article.

Comment: It is the use of the word "probability" in the wikipedia article instead of "likelihood" (as you correctly call it) that is the cause of the confusion.  In fact, earlier in the article, it says "Then, the **probability** (_emphasis added_) of some value given a class, $P(x = v \mid c)$, can be computed by plugging $v$ into the equation for a Normal distribution parameterized by $\mu_c$ and $\sigma^2_c$" which is nonsensical from a probability theory viewpoint but not uncommon in applied statistical circles.